# Implementation of Cookies in Play 2.0 Framework

Tags: scala, cookies, playframework-2.0

Hope you are doing well,

I have a problem in implement cookies in play 2.0 framework. In my application, i gave search 
functionality. Now i am want to store recent search data in cookies but till now i unable to implement .

Please if any body implement cookies in play 2.0 then suggest me.

Thanks 
Anuj

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaSessionFlash

You can use session to store your data with "withSession" instruction.